# upgrading to .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-7.0

I have upgraded a .net core 2.1 app to .NET 7 and resolved all the compilation errors and it builds successfully but when run, I am getting the following error: (I have installed .NET 7.0.11)

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime
Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Specific error detected by ANCM:
You must install or update .NET to run this application. App: {path}\bin\Debug\net7.0\{appname}.Web.dll Architecture: x64 Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.11' (x64) .NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\ The following frameworks were found: 2.1.30 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 3.1.21 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 5.0.12 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 5.0.14 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 6.0.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 6.0.14 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 6.0.21 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] 7.0.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App] Learn about framework resolution: https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed To install missing framework, download: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=7.0.11&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
Troubleshooting steps:
```

Any help would be great. thanks

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing framework?

Comment: Yes. that was it. I had to install the run time on top of the framework

Comment: It seems that, you have migrated the full project at once, this is not the right way to upgrade version because in this way, you cannot understand what exactly went wrong. Instead, what you can do is, try to move feature incrementally and then run, this way you can keep tract what do you need and what you don't and you can easily migrate.

Comment: Hi @wenbingeng-MSFT, After installing the correct runtime, it's working fine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message you provided, your computer lacks the necessary .NET 7.0 Runtime.

You can enter "DOTNET -INFO" in CMD to see which one is missing .NET 7.0 Runtime.

As follows:

[image]

[image]

Finally, on [this website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-s/download/dotnet/7.0?ocid=aid3042760), download the corresponding .NET 7.0 Runtime and installed and install

Of course you can also install in Visual Studio Installer .NET 7.0 Runtime

If this does not work, please let me know.